# How to read browser url in sitecore jss

Tags: reactjs, url, browser, sitecore

I tried to read browser url(this.props.location) in **sitecore** jss scaffold component but not able to get that.

Can anybody help with this to read browser url please ?

**or**

Is it possible to read window url in sitecore jss like normal javascript/reactjs?

Comment: Any code about what you have done till now may help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`document.location` might be what you are looking for. Assuming you are talking about client-side JS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location

Answer (score 0):

There is no special need to read browser url.

Using javascript `window.location` or `document.location` we can read.

```
console.log(window.location)
```